# Custom UIButton hit and UIImagePickerController buttons background

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using this extension of UIButton witch ignore taps on transparent color of buttons

```
open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if (!self.bounds.contains(point)) {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        let color : UIColor = self.getColourFromPoint(point: point)
        let alpha = color.cgColor.alpha;
        if alpha <= 0.0 {
            debugPrint("no tocado")
            return nil
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

When i call UIImagePickerController the buttons has only text with transparent background, making hard to hit them...

There is some way to detect the context of the Buttons to avoid this extension in UIImagePickerController?
or put some background in the buttons of UIImagePickerController them without a custom picker?

Thanks!

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Please try to explain it again.

Comment: done, I have an extension for UIbuttons but i wanna avoid that behaviour it in the uiimagepickercontroller of the Camera ty!

Comment: i updated my answer. Could you check if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this at the start of your hitTest function:

```
if self.isKind(of: UIImagePickerController.self){
    return nil
}
```

Comment: nope, doesn't works, the buttons are UIButton type, but i need to know from witch class /context are called

Comment: @User22 i have the feeling that you do something really complicated for an easy problem. What do you want to archive? Why do the buttons have alpha = 0 and not just hidden?